# Launch a background Thread by using a JButton

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, events, jbutton

I'm not confident with Java, but I'm developing a tool for monitoring our company Server HDisks because of some problems we have.

I've been creating a simple frame with a simple menu and a `JPanel` with some information, but it is not important.

My idea is simply: press the `JButton` of the `JFrame`, then my service (which is a class extends `Thread` and sleeps for a while each cycle) starts.
I made all the classes, but I have this problem: when I press the button, the background class starts, but I lose control of the main frame.

How can I separate the frame class between my background class?

Comment: if you have the code working other than making the button launch it, consider adding an action listener to the button.  see [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Thank you guys, I've solved the problem.At least, it was

Answer (score 0):

> then my service (which is a Class extends Thread and sleeps for a while each cycle) starts. I made all the classes, but I have this problem: when I press my JButton, the background class starts, but I loose control of the main JFrame.

Not exactly sure what "loose control of the main JFrame" means. But I'm guessing it no longer responds to user events.

This would be because your Thread.sleep is causing the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` to sleep, so you are either:

1. not creating the Thread correctly, or
2. sleeping the wrong Thread.

In any case I would suggest that in the ActionListener you add to your button that you start a `SwingWorker`. A `SwingWorker` will create the Thread for you and it allows you to communicate properly with the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples to get you started. The tutorial will explain more about the `EDT`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information? 
But for what I understood you should add an event listener to your JButton.
Example code:

```
    BackGroundThread task = new BackGroundThread();
    JButton btn = new JButton("Run task");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {            
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            task.start();
        }
    });
```